# Unity Tilemaps and maps in general

Tags: database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

i am making 2d tile-based **mobile** game. Question is about saving maps(about 100). The first idea was to make local sql lite database with each object's name ,coordinate, angle... but then came new tilemap update. Maybe i can make 100 tilemaps(or grids with multiple tilemaps in it) in one scene and activate/deactivate when loading new level? What do you think? And databases (sqllite) are fast on phone with unity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend just making a serializable pure C# class called "Tile" or similar, containing the variables you've mentioned, and then have another serializable class with an array of those.  Then just use the serialization built into Unity to pipe them out to persistent path data files.  Note though that there can be issues with serializing on iOS due to JIT restrictions, but if your types aren't too complex then simple binary or even JSON serialization will work.  (The open source tool Protobuf-NET is a good option if you do need complex iOS serializing.)

Anyway, SQLite is good and does work on mobile, but is probably not going to be worth the effort you'd need to deal with it if all you're doing is saving out data.  I'd only reach for a database solution if you actually need to do complex queries on the data, otherwise just go for serializing.